# emberjs newbie - map function not defined for router

Tags: ember.js, ember-old-router

I am just starting with emberjs. I am creating a simple index.html page with two links on top: About and Posts. This is following the standard example on emberjs homepage. I get an error in the browser

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'map' of undefined"

So this means that my router is undefined. Why is that?

Here is the app.js code:

```
var App = Ember.Application.create();

App.router.map(function(){

});
```

So I tried to define it ...

```
var App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  enableLogging: true,
  location: 'hash'
});

App.Router.map(function(){

});
```

I still get the error. I am confused :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using the latest version of Ember (1.0.0-RC.2) from http://emberjs.com/.

The example you posted is the old style router which is not used anymore.  The new style is explained in [this guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/) and is defined like this:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route("about", { path: "/about" });
  this.route("favorites", { path: "/favs" });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So I came across another question on stackoverflow. http://goo.gl/JVEs9. I got a version of ember (1.0.0-pre.2) from the link and re-wrote the code as follows:

```
var App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function(match){
    match('/').to('index');
    match('about').to('about');  
});
```

This seems to work. I still cannot get:

```
var App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource('about');
});
```

I get the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'resource'

Answer (score 0):

A resource is not an end point. Try the following:

```
App.Router.map(function() {

  this.resource('about', function() {
  });

});
```